# How do I set the color to default if user doesn't specify it?

Tags: php

I want the user to enter the desired color to be set as background color, but if it is not set, I want it to be set to silver.

It doesn't work anyway, but this is what I wrote so far and now I'm stuck!

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['bgColor']))
    $bgColor = $_GET['bgColor'];
else
    $bgColor = 'silver';

echo "You chose the {$bgColor}" . " color.";
?>
```

Form:

```
<form action="w3.php" method="get">
    <label>Background Color:</label><input type="text" name="bgColor">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Style is set to `body{background-color: <?php echo $bgColor; ?>;}`

Comment: It work for me. where you put `body{background-color: <?php echo $bgColor; ?>;}` ?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is if you pass any color other than silver, it still sets the bg to silver.

Comment: Have to ask, do you have the css in the PHP-file or in a separate css-file?

Comment: In the PHP file

Comment: What do you get if you do a `var_dump($_GET)` before the if statement? (You should be able to see it in the URL as well, though)

Comment: Hi Magnus Eriksson, thanks for your reply. My initial problem is solved. If textbox is empty, bgColor is set to the else statement. However, when you enter mumbo jumbo, it sets it to white, or default, I guess. How can I resolve that? I used          if(!empty($_GET['bgColor']) || isset($_GET['bgColor']))
        $bgColor = $_GET['bgColor']; but it's no good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the following code to change the background color - Try putting the body tag inside if else:

```
if (Condition) 
{
  echo '<body style="background-color:blue">';
}
else 
{
  echo '<body style="background-color:white">';
}
```

**Updated**: I've updated your code and little help from developer. The code is working. Check it:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['bgColor']))
    $bgColor = $_GET['bgColor'];
else
    $bgColor = 'silver';

echo "You chose the {$bgColor}" . " color.";
?>
<form action="w3.php" method="get">
    <label>Background Color:</label><input type="text" name="bgColor">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<style type="text/css">
    body{background-color: <?php echo $bgColor;?>;}
</style>
```

Just write the color name like blue, red and it'll be changing in the next page:

w3.php -

```
<?php
?>

<style type="text/css">
    body{background-color: <?php echo $_GET['bgColor']?>;}
</style>
```

Done nothing here. Just grabbed the QueryString value from url that's the color name.

Comment: Why _should_ he be using this instead of his current code? An explanation would be nice.

Comment: I guess, the code explains much. He didn't mention about how he dealt with body tag. Just got him a hint.

Comment: AT-2016: Is there a way to stick to CSS and not change the style in HTML tags?

Comment: Not saying that the example is bad or that it's hard to understand. My point was more that if you tell someone that they _should_ do something in another way, you _should_ provide a good reason for it. :)

Comment: AT-2016: I've written the exact same thing and it sets the bg to silver regardless of what you enter.

Comment: The background color gets changed. Then where do you want the color to be changed in the next page or the current one?

Comment: in the PHP file (w3.php)

Comment: The page color will be changed now. Check the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not write the code in a good order.

For example look how this code works:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['bgColor']))
    $bgColor = $_GET['bgColor'];
else
    $bgColor = 'silver';

echo "You chose the {$bgColor}" . " color.";
?>
<form action="w3.php" method="get">
    <label>Background Color:</label><input type="text" name="bgColor">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<style type="text/css">
    body{background-color: <?php echo $bgColor;?>;}
</style>
```

this is how to set the color after receive the form input:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body{background-color: <?php echo $bgColor;?>;}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems identical to what I wrote so far. The instructions inside the if statement don't trigger.